# How to debug a Rails app on a different port (not default port 3000) on VS Code on MacOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm on MacOS Sierra and use rbenv.

Here is my configuration for my Rails server configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Rails server",
    "type": "Ruby",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "useBundler": true,
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
    "args": [
        "server"
    ]
}
```

I've tried the following values for the "args" key:

```
"args": [
    "server",
    "-p 4002"
]
```

But I would get the following error:

```
Exiting
bundler: failed to load command: rdebug-ide (/Users/knockycode/vendor/bundle/bin/rdebug-ide)
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- rack/handler/-p 4002
```

Comment: Hi, I had another issue: `Don't know how to build task 'server -p 3001'` with similar config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out that `-p 4002` contains TWO arguments: the `-p` flag, and `4002` flag value; it's not one whole argument.

The working configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Rails server",
    "type": "Ruby",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "useBundler": true,
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
    "args": [
        "server",
        "-p",
        "4002"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thx a million you are a saviour, this solved my issue (in the comment of the question). Cheers!